# Getting parent width using angular

Tags: angularjs

Trying to write a directive which basically sets the height of a button to the width of the containing div (OK, I'll probably add a bit of a margin, but for now its width)

My problem is, how do I get the width of the containing div. 
So the HTML looks as follows:

```
   <div bigbutton="">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-icon center-block"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i><br><h6>Add one</h6></button>
   </div>
```

Tried the following (which works, but on window size)

```
app.directive('bigbutton', function ($window) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            var winWidth = $window.clientWidth;
            console.log("Window width: " + winWidth)
            var winHeight = winWidth
            elem.css('height', winWidth + 'px');
            elem.css('width', winHeight + 'px');
            elem.css('background-color', 'black');
        }
    };
});
```

Tried to use event (found some text that said that could do the trick, but cant get the injector to accept $event)

```
app.directive('bigbutton', function ($window, $event) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, elem) {

            var winWidth = $($event.target).parent().outerWidth();
            console.log("Window width: " + winWidth)
            var winHeight = winWidth
            elem.css('height', winWidth + 'px');
            elem.css('width', winHeight + 'px');
            elem.css('background-color', 'black');
        }
    };
});
```

Think I might be barking up the wrong tree though.

Comment: Why are you using `restrict: 'A'` for a directive you are applying as a class?  You should either use `restrict: 'C'` or apply the directive as its own attribute on the button (`<button class="" bigbutton>`)  Also, your casing for the directive name should be `bigButton` if you want to call it `big-button` in the markup.

Comment: Well, I am not certain what A vs C does, but if I put it as C it stops working completely (does not change the code at all). Also, I am sorry, copied the wrong HTML (editing now)

Comment: restrict is for defining what kind of directive it is.  Attribute, Element, Class.

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally found it. Was going wrong with going for parent. 
The trick seems to be elem[0] instead of elem.parrent

```
app.directive('bigbutton', function ($window) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, elem) {

            var winWidth = elem[0].clientWidth;
                //elem.parent().width;
            console.log("Window width: " + winWidth)
            var winHeight = winWidth
            elem.css('height', winWidth + 'px');
            elem.css('width', winHeight + 'px');
            elem.css('background-color', 'black');
        }
    };
});
```